# Exception when using Action class with PageObject IWebElement

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

In my PageObject Class a IWebElement is definded as follows:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//input[contains(@ng-model,'model.BrancheName')]/following-sibling::span")]
private IWebElement TooltipBrancheName;
```

The following Method gets the text of this Tooltip:

```
public string GetTooltiptekstDatabaseBranche()
        {
            string text = TooltipBrancheName.GetAttribute("class");
            Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
            actions.MoveToElement(TooltipBrancheName).Perform();
            //actions.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[contains(@ng-model,'model.BrancheName')]/following-sibling::span"))).Perform();
            return TooltipBrancheName.GetAttribute("title");
        }
```

When I call this method from my test class a **System.Refelection.TargetException: Object does not match target type.** Exception is thrown on the line with the MoveToElement method.

The first line of code in the method is only present to check the ToolTipBrancheName IWebElement property exists and is not Null, which is the case because it gives me the correct value for the class attribute.

When I uncomment the commented line and comment the line wich gives the exception the method works fine. The locator used is the same in both lines. I'm curious what causes this exception, field *ToolTipBrancheName* exists, is not Null and is of the right type **IWebElement**.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one on second line, maybe it works:

```
private IWebElement TooltipBrancheName {get; set;}
```

Answer (score 0):

A little history:

I actually stumbled across the same exception yesterday when testing a method that compares two DTOs using reflection. The problem in my case, was that I accidentally used two different DTO classes (e.g. `ServerDTO, AccountDTO`), and when reflection got the property from the first DTO, it couldn't find it in the second.

The WILD guess:

I'm gonna take a longshot here and guess that what your `FindsBy` returns is not the same as what the `WebDriver` returns. If your driver is (e.g.) `ChromeDriver`, it returns a `ChromeWebElement`, but MAYBE, FindsBy (since the attribute is independed from the webdriver), returns an IWebElement (it uses the `WebElement` interface).

BUT

When you use `Actions actions = new Actions(driver);`, it's possible that it must use WebDriver's objects (`ChromeWebElement`, `FireFoxWebElement`, depends on what driver you use). When `Perform()` runs, it uses reflection to get the WebElement's properties (the exception is a dead giveaway). At this point, perhaps it assumes that the element is a `ChromeWebElement` and not a `IWebElement`, (hence the exception, it tries to get something that the `ChromeWebElement` has but not the `IWebElement`, like what I stumbled across with the DTOs).

P.S. What I stated above, is pure assumption, but maybe it could be a hit to help further investigation.